# Linux partition deleted, GRUB no longer boots

Tags: ubuntu, grub, multi-boot, bootloader

My notebook computer came with Vista and I installed Ubuntu on 2 partitions and kubuntu on another partition.

After a while, I wanted to delete one of the Ubuntu partition, so I did it in Vista's Disk Management Tool.

But after that, the computer won't boot up.  Grub reports:

```
Loading Stage1.5  
GRUB Loading, please wait...  
Error 22
```

What can be done to make the computer boot up again?  Is it true that if EasyBCD can be run, then it would fix the error?  Right now, it seems that I can only boot up the Ubuntu 9.04 install DVD again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GRUB is a program that is loaded in various stages. Normally you will start GRUB on the MBR (master boot record) where there is the "pointer" to where the rest of GRUB is installed, so that GRUB can go on with stage 1.5 or 2.0.

What is happening to you seems like the MBR is still there, but the rest of the stages have gone with the partition, so basically you have to tell GRUB to look for those stages in the other (k)ubuntu installation, the one you did not erase.

From what I understand, I think you can procede by doing the following:

1. Boot your system from either ubuntu or kubuntu live CD.
2. Mount the partitions on your HD where your ubuntu/kubuntu has been installed previously (Can't remember if this is automatic in ubuntu 9.10 or if you have to double-click on the icons on the desktop).
3. Open a Terminal and type `sudo -i`. This will give you root privileges in that shall.
4. Type `grub` which makes a GRUB prompt appear.
5. Type `find /boot/grub/stage1`. You'll get a response like `(hd0)` or `(hd0, X)`, where X is a number. Note down what the computer says as you are going to use this in next steps (I will refer to this as "(XXX)" in the rest of this how-to. This actually find out where the missing pieces of your grub installation are (it will return the ubuntu partition you have not erased)
6. Type `root (XXX)`. This allows GRUB to load those pieces.
7. Type `setup (XXX)`. This actually "fix" the broken GRUB.
8. Type `quit`.
9. You can now reboot your machine normally.

If I understand correctly, you first had Vista, then you installed ubuntu#1 and then ubuntu#2, and then you deleted ubuntu#2. If you did so, after this you will be pretty much done. Should the windows option not show up in the GRUB menu, you will have to issue the command `update-grub` or maually edit (only for ubuntu up to 9.04 but not for 9.10) the file **/boot/grub/menu.lst** (it is pretty straightforward).

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

There is the [SuperGrubDisk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org),
I have not really used it but maybe some here knows the tricks,
or, you could just get it on a disk and try.

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=224351 Check this link. It should help.