# Why SuperGrubDisk won't boot up anything?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub, bootloader

I burned a SuperGrubDisk by going to

> http://developer.berlios.de/project/showfiles.php?group_id=10921

and downloading

> grub-rescue-cdrom.iso

which is

> http://prdownload.berlios.de/supergrub/grub-rescue-cdrom.iso

so, by using Win7, I can burn the ISO onto a DVD-R.

Now I put that DVD-R into the notebook computer, and when it boots, it lets me choose

```
First kernel and intrd
```

and it is the only choice, so i chose it, and it says error:

> Error: no kernel loaded

Is this the correct way to run SuperGrubDisk?

This is related to the issue on
[Linux Partition deleted and grub no longer boots](https://superuser.com/questions/70745/linux-partition-deleted-grub-no-longer-boots)

Comment: No need to use the DVD on something so small, I suggest using a USB flash drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of SGD are you using? I just tried v. 1.21 from [here](http://prdownload.berlios.de/supergrub/sgd_cdrom_1.21.iso.gz) and for me it works without any problem. The screenshot I get looks like this:

[image]

The only thing that surprised me about your question is that you managed to burn a CD iso onto a DVD... I did not know it was possible (but I am not suggesting you are wrong here!). Do you obtain the same results by booting from a USB stick?

Comment: ok, looks like the one I have downloaded was 1.01 2009-07-26 00:00 grub-rescue-cdrom.iso I just saw one was a .gz and one was a .iso, so i thought they are the same except one is compressed... so i am burning the version 1.21 to a DVD-R now... the reason is I don't have a lot of CD-R left but I have a lot of DVD-R left... and CD-R was like 20 cents each while DVD-R is like 30 cents each... but I don't think I will buy CD-R much in the future, so I am using DVD-R. I burn Ubuntu install disc to DVD-R and they work too.

Comment: The choice of CD-R vs DVD-R media makes no difference in this case