# Does SuperGrubDisk fix the boot menu for us or do we need to do it manually?

Tags: windows, multi-boot, grub, supergrubdisk, easybcd

So I am using version 1.21 of SuperGrubDisk, and is able to boot up Vista now with it.

(for some screenshot please see [Why SuperGrubDisk won't boot up anything?](https://superuser.com/questions/71084/why-supergrubdisk-wont-boot-up-anything))

But does it have an option to automatically fix the boot menu?

If not, must I use the command line on Linux, or can I just boot up Vista, and run EasyBCD and fix everything?

Or, if I install Win 7 on the computer, will it wipe out the boot menu for all Ubuntu installation (i have 2) any way?  In that case I may as well install Win 7 first and then fix the Ubuntu boot menu afterwards.

Also, can't I just install Win 7 first, and then install Ubuntu 9.10 on a new partition (or overwrite an old Ubuntu 9.04 partition), and then I will have all the boot menu back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SGD should have an option to repair a broken GRUB menu, but it didn't work for me when I tried a few hours ago, (probably my dodgy system). Look through the help, but I think it is the 3rd menu option from memory to automagically repair.

I suggest burning SGD to a CD rather than a USB, because when I did this it got confused, and thought the USB was hd0.

Installing Windows 7 will make the windows partition the boot partition and so you won't see GRUB, but Ubuntu will when it installs GRUB

I recommend:

1. Install Windows 7
2. Install Ubuntu (over your old ubuntu installation)

Doing this will give you both windows and linux. The ubuntu installation will give you a brand new GRUB menu with (hopefully) a windows 7 link which you will get when you boot up.

If any of that doesn't work, you should still be able  to access your ubuntu installation where you can edit your GRUB menu with:

```
sudo nano /boot/grub/menu.lst
```